# React native Expo error trying to sign in with Google federated in apple device

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am trying to implement google federated sign in, with AWS Amplify, in react native manged flow by expo, and a get a weird error only in my apple physical device.

I followed the documentation in `<https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/#full-samples>` and got this code:

```js
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { Button, Linking, Platform, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
    import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
    
    async function urlOpener(url, redirectUrl) {
      const { type, url: newUrl } = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
        url,
        redirectUrl,
      );
    
      if (type === 'success' && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();
        return Linking.openURL(newUrl);
      }
    }
    
    const [
      localRedirectSignIn,
      productionRedirectSignIn,
    ] = awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignIn.split(",");
    
    const [
      localRedirectSignOut,
      productionRedirectSignOut,
    ] = awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignOut.split(",");
    
    
    Amplify.configure({
      .    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:27777e6d-857e-4187-84b6-85a17891d320",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_MLaD0VGx7",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "6kanfftqjuu7pgv7415or1hkl9",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "velpaf3732cb1-f3732cb1-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "phone",
            "profile"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/,
        "redirectSignOut": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/,
        "responseType": "token"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_AND_IDENTITY_POOLS",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://tlpmf7idfvextlpbc4qrrmwgfy.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "da2-3tpwvu3nobf35bk4mmx3m3gfnq",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": "velpanewversion3d014069f75d4be1bc2875498e9be3dc193449-staging",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": "us-east-1"
    });
    
    function App() {
      const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
          switch (event) {
            case 'signIn':
              getUser().then((userData) => setUser(userData));
              break;
            case 'signOut':
              setUser(null);
              break;
            case 'signIn_failure':
            case 'cognitoHostedUI_failure':
              console.log('Sign in failure', data);
              break;
          }
        });
    
        getUser().then((userData) => setUser(userData));
      }, []);
    
      function getUser() {
        return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
          .then((userData) => userData)
          .catch(() => console.log('Not signed in'));
      }
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>User: {user ? JSON.stringify(user.attributes) : 'None'}</Text>
          {user ? (
            <Button title="Sign Out" onPress={() => Auth.signOut()} />
          ) : (
            <Button title="Federated Sign In" onPress={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()} />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

This is my awsExport:

```js
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:27777e6d-857e-4187-84b6-85a17891d320",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_MLaD0VGx7",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "6kanfftqjuu7pgv7415or1hkl9",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "velpaf3732cb1-f3732cb1-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "phone",
            "profile"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/,exp://exp.host/@mateodelat/velpa/",
        "redirectSignOut": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/,exp://exp.host/@mateodelat/velpa/",
        "responseType": "token"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_AND_IDENTITY_POOLS",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://tlpmf7idfvextlpbc4qrrmwgfy.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "da2-3tpwvu3nobf35bk4mmx3m3gfnq",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": "velpanewversion3d014069f75d4be1bc2875498e9be3dc193449-staging",
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": "us-east-1"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

When I do the sign in with google from my virtual emulator device I can do a successful login.

Logging from my physical apple device, I can open the web browser but once authorized from google, get the following screen:
[Image error](https://i.postimg.cc/gcq5F7Bq/Whats-App-Image-2021-09-07-at-13-32-30.jpg)

Comment: The document is literally an example. You should get a configuration key that fits your account.

Comment: What do you mean @hongdeveloper?

Comment: In the example of the document, aws_appsync_apiKey is literally an example.

Comment: Yes I know it, it's my example